# What would be the fastest method?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm building a dashboard using ASP.Net MVC, Angular.js, SQL Server and Fusion charts. All my data for charting is stored in database and I'm getting them via stored procedure. Now I need to pass the results from stored procedure to Json/XML, only formats Fusion Charts supports. What would be the best method to convert this data:

```
Hour Input   Output  InTarget  OutTarget
7    22314   18537    6500      4875
8    36395   29931    6500      4875
9    32661   28518    6500      4875
10   34895   29793    6500      4875
11   30300   26538    6500      4875
12   31011   26898    6500      4875
13   16363   13716    6500      4875
```

into this Json?

```
{
                "chart": {
                    "caption": "Input and Output",
                    "numberprefix": "$",
                    "plotgradientcolor": "",
                    "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
                    "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
                    "divlinecolor": "CCCCCC",
                    "showvalues": "0",
                    "showcanvasborder": "0",
                    "canvasborderalpha": "0",
                    "canvasbordercolor": "CCCCCC",
                    "canvasborderthickness": "1",
                    "yaxismaxvalue": "30000",
                    "captionpadding": "30",
                    "yaxisvaluespadding": "15",
                    "legendshadow": "0",
                    "legendborderalpha": "0",
                    "palettecolors": "#f8bd19,#008ee4,#33bdda,#e44a00,#6baa01,#583e78",
                    "showplotborder": "0",
                    "showborder": "0"
                },
                "categories": [
                    {
                        "category": [
                            {
                                "label": "7"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "8"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "9"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "10"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "11"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "12"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "13"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ],
                "dataset": [
                    {
                        "seriesname": "Input",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "value": "22314"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "36395"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "32661"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "34895"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "30300"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "31011"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "16363"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "seriesname": "Output",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "value": "18537"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "29931"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "28518"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "29793"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "26538"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "26898"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "13716"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "seriesname": "InTarget",
                        "renderas": "Line",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "6500"
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    {
                        "seriesname": "OutTarget",
                        "renderas": "Line",
                        "data": [
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            },
                            {
                                "value": "4875"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
```

What I'm thinking to do is:

- stored procedure into datatable
- put each column into separate array
- convert array to Json in the format below

Is this going to be the best (performance) approach?

EDIT:

```
        public Series[] GetGraphData(string sp)
    {
        var connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EFDbContext"].ConnectionString;
        using (var da = new SqlDataAdapter("exec " + sp, connection))
        {
            var dt = new DataTable();

            da.Fill(dt);
            da.FillSchema(dt, SchemaType.Mapped);


            Series[] arrSeries = new Series[dt.Columns.Count];


            foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
            {
                if (dc.Ordinal == 0)
                {
                  //Category here
                }
                else
                {
                    var strarr = dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().Select(row => row[dc.Ordinal]).ToList();

                    Series s = new Series()
                    {
                        seriesname = dc.ColumnName,
                        renderas = "Line",
                        data = strarr.Select(o => new SeriesValue { value = o.ToString() }).ToList()
                    };

                    arrSeries[dc.Ordinal] = s;
                }
            }

            return arrSeries;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would load all the data into a datatable as you said, then have a Series object:

```
class Series{
  public string seriesname{get;set;}
  public string renderas{get;set;}
  public IList<SeriesValue> data{get;set;}
}

class SeriesValue{
  public string value{get;set;}
}
```

and return an array of Series to the frontend, serialized as JSON. Then you have the `dataset` array already built and you don't need to do any other processing on it.

I expect the performance bottleneck to be in loading the data from the db and sending it to the client .. the actual conversion to json shouldn't matter in the grand scheme of things.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, can you look on my code (I edited question), how to load the column values to IList<SeriesValue>?